# Importing second file in already imported file causing errors?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

Okay so I have googled this a *ton* and tried the solutions listed on stackoverflow... but none of them have worked.

I am in anaconda, if that matters. I have a python file called 'mainwithai.py'. In that file, I do:

```
from SAI import AI_Player
```

Which works fine. SAI.py is in the same directory as mainwithai. Now, in that same directory, is a file called "getboards.py".

I tried to import this in SAI, *not* in mainwithai, in the same way, and it failed. I tried it a couple different ways and it fails, based on the different answers I've seen, here are a few:

```
from . import getboards
import getboards
from .. import getboards
from getboards import *
```

getboards has no classes, if that matters (SAI.py has a class). Just a collection of functions and some random dictionaries those functions need. It likewise doesn't matter if I try the import in mainwithai or SAI, same errors.

Why does SAI work, and getboards fails? I see that there are .pyc files for mainwithai and sai in the folder; do I need one of those for getboards too?

I've read something about `__init__.py`, but it sounds like that's for something entirely different than what I'm trying to do; I just want to hit f5 on mainwithai and have it go, not make a package.

EDIT:
Adding output of ls

```
 Volume in drive D is YSTORAGE
 Volume Serial Number is 60BA-9F15

 Directory of D:\AllStuff\writtenworks\StrategoProject

07/27/2018  11:42 AM    <DIR>          .
07/27/2018  11:42 AM    <DIR>          ..
01/26/2018  10:14 AM                66 .gitattributes
01/29/2018  11:05 AM                70 .gitignore
11/06/2018  09:17 AM    <DIR>          __pycache__
12/29/2017  12:26 AM             7,812 AI.py
01/30/2018  11:56 AM    <DIR>          AI_Mode
01/02/2018  03:22 PM    <DIR>          backups
12/29/2017  12:42 AM               231 conf.cfg
01/31/2018  09:52 AM    <DIR>          Database
12/31/2017  09:45 PM               336 empty.txt
12/31/2017  09:28 PM               336 gamestate.txt
11/13/2018  02:57 PM            16,352 getboards.py
12/31/2017  06:27 PM           125,862 gurobi.log
01/26/2018  10:14 AM            35,119 LICENSE
11/13/2018  03:41 PM            34,443 mainwithai.py
01/02/2018  11:11 PM            20,259 mainwithai.pyc
11/08/2018  02:06 PM            16,268 mcts.py
01/24/2018  01:11 PM                 0 mintemps.txt
12/29/2017  04:26 PM             1,322 model.ilp
11/08/2018  09:11 AM         8,252,424 neuralstrategoALL.h5
12/31/2017  06:08 PM             6,827 optimization_setup.py
01/29/2018  10:40 AM    <DIR>          optimizedsetups
01/26/2018  10:14 AM                18 README.md
09/08/2017  03:05 PM    <DIR>          resources
11/13/2018  03:40 PM            12,747 SAI.py
01/26/2018  01:08 PM             5,666 SAI.pyc
11/06/2018  10:51 AM             8,872 SAIbackup.txt
11/09/2018  11:10 AM             4,226 strategoneural.py
12/31/2017  09:06 PM               337 testtest.txt
12/31/2017  09:00 PM               336 texttext.txt
11/07/2018  04:59 PM             4,992 xmlparse2.py
              24 File(s)      8,554,921 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  20,052,148,224 bytes free
```

EDIT 2: here are all the imports at the top of all three files:

mainwithai:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import configparser
import sys, time, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import re
from SAI import AI_Player
```

SAI:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from copy import copy
import re
```

getboards:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
from copy import copy, deepcopy
```

I don't import anywhere but at the top, that's all of them I checked (I searched the files as a matter of course though), so I don't think it's a circular reference. The only thing they have in common is that getboards has a dictionary with the same name as SAI, but other than that I checked all the function names even; nothing.

EDIT 3: Stacktrace of putting `import getboards` in SAI.py

```
runfile('D:/AllStuff/writtenworks/StrategoProject/SAI.py', wdir='D:/AllStuff/writtenworks/StrategoProject')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-895-2df6678e9989>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/AllStuff/writtenworks/StrategoProject/SAI.py', wdir='D:/AllStuff/writtenworks/StrategoProject')

  File "C:\Users\ylwaller\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\sdev3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 678, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\ylwaller\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\sdev3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 106, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/AllStuff/writtenworks/StrategoProject/SAI.py", line 8, in <module>
    import getboards

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'getboards'
```

Comment: *How* does it fail? And are you sure you don't have a circular import?

Comment: Nah no circular import, getboards only imports numpy and copy. Ah, I get various forms of "cannot import name 'getboards'" or "No module named 'getboards'" "attempted relative import with no known parent package" (for from .dir import getboards)

Comment: I think `import getboards` and `from getboards import *` should work. But yes, you can't do the relative imports (i.e. using `.` or `..` in the `import` statement) without using `__init__.py`s (AFAIK). You're sure there are no typos (like you accidentally named it `getbaords.py` or something?

Comment: Nah it's sitting right there as getboards.py, this is why I'm confused as from SAI import AI_Player works just fine in mainwithai... so i'm really confused as to why it fails for a different file

Comment: Me too. Can you paste the output of `tree` or `ls` from the directory you're talking about? There's something that is missing here: because what you're describing should work. Everything is in one directory, right?

Comment: These three files are all in one directory, mainwithai reads in some images and various other things from another sub-folder, but it's been doing that since before I added SAI.

Comment: I'm not convinced you don't have circular dependency somewhere. At least that's how you can get the `cannot import name 'blah'` error. I think it can also happen if the line endings in the files don't match (like one is from linux, one from windows), or if the files don't have the same encodings. Make sure they are all UTF8 (well, or whatever, just make sure they're the same), use dos2unix or unix2dos, and further *triple check* that you have no circular imports.

Comment: Can you add the *exact* stack trace that happens when you do `import getboards` from `SAI.py` and run the main?

Comment: I put it in there! The stacktrace looks essentially the same if I try to import in mainwithai instead, only difference is the file name n such

Comment: What in the world is `runfile`? That can only be trouble and complicating the issue. What happens if you just run it from your shell (i.e. `python SAI.py` or `python mainwithai.py`)?

Comment: runfile is the command that gets send when I hit f5 (shortcut for running the file as one may expect) in anaconda. Hmmm well that's bloody damn weird. It completes the run with no errors when I do it from my prompt... oh lord down the rabbit hole of anaconda problems then

Comment: It isn't Anaconda, it's Spyder. Did some googling/reading. You may have found a bug in Spyder.

Comment: Alright thanks for all the help I appreciate your time a lot, I'll go pester them on github and see what comes of it!